# Job was completed, job has completed and job has been completed?

Tags: expressions, idiomatic-language

I have written an email which I believe the sentence was incorrect.

> Mr. A, Mowing at the job site has completed.

It could be better if I say: "Mowing *was completed* at the job site" or "mowing *has been completed*".

But how odd was the original one? Do people consider that was just a typo or people can tell that I am not a native speaker because the structure of the sentence was incorrect?

I am asking the damage of the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

It's a very minor mistake that does have a twinge of ESL learner to it, if only because it implies a level of detachment that may be accidental. 'Completed' without 'has been' or 'was' implies that you care more about the status of the lawn than about the people that mowed it. If I hired a service to mow my lawn every Thursday while I'm at work and I don't know any of the workers by name, this phrasing might be appropriate. But if you're the one mowing or know the person, acknowledging the source of the act is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Carduus. The only thing I would add is to remember that English prefers to maintain a "Subject Verb Object" order. Keeping that in mind,

> Mowing was completed at the job site.

would be preferred. Though, again, I do agree with Carduus' answer.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the OP's order. Sticking with SVO order without relief leads to tedious and boring writing.

Comment: I agree with the tediousness of a constant SVO. I thought, for this question, it would be appropriate to maintain that order. :)